# Getting the previous and next elements of a collection for a known one

Tags: java, collections, iterator, java-stream

How to get the next and previous collection item for a known item?

**The "stage" object is known, you need to get the previous and next for it, if any**

I tried to do this, but it fails(

```
Iterator<Stage> it = project.getProjectStages().iterator();
    for (Stage stage1:
         project.getProjectStages()) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (stage1.getStageId() == stage.getStageId()) {
                nextStage = it.next();
                previousStage = nextStage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to the get the `next` and the `previous` for the **final** stage. Is that all you want? Because that's how I read your code. Also, you probably meant to assign `previous` ***before*** `next` (as is, they're the same).

Comment: This is not a good fit for the stream framework.  Doing it with an iterator is the right way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem that I don’t know how to correctly determine the previous and next elements, if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is pretty broken unfortunately. You have the `next` statement inside an `if` so you are risking an endless loop. And the iteration is inside another iteration risking multiple use of the same iterator.

I suspect you want something like:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    current = iter.next();
    if (current.getStageId() == target) {
         if (iter.hasNext())
             following = iter.next();
         break;
    }
    previous = current;
}
```